# Pydantic' settings having weird key value error

Tags: python, config, pydantic

I've recently decided to switch to using Pydantics BaseSettings for loading up config in my project and it's working great with one issue and I am not sure how to fix it. I don't really understand the issue at all.

I have a Setting class like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings, root_validator

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    my_obj: obj
    age: int = 25
    old_person: bool = False

    @root_validator
    def validate_old_person(cls, values):
      values['old_person'] = values['my_obj'].enabled
      return values
```

and I am calling the Settings with object instance properly some like `Settings(my_obj = obj_method)` where the obj_method returns the instance of the object. However when running this I keep getting `KeyError: 'my_obj'` and I do not understand why. Is there some hidden process that renders the object before it's instance? I have same logic in my other Settings classes and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Could you post the whole error? Also just make sure you saved your file and that you're running a correct version of your thing

Comment: Also, according to docs: "As with field validators, "post" (i.e. pre=False) root validators by default will be called even if prior validators fail; this behaviour can be changed by setting the skip_on_failure=True keyword argument to the validator." - do you maybe have some plain Settings() (without argument) before that? It would fail on that

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes the code that actually instantiates your `Settings` object and the full error message. Also it is not clear what `obj` is in the annotation `my_obj: obj`. It looks strange because fields are supposed to be annotated with **types**. So please include everything we need to reproduce your problem in your code snippet.